# Unable to Install Visual Studio Code Extensions

Tags: c#, sockets, visual-studio-code

**I raised this as an issue on the [VSCode github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7529#issuecomment-225229352)**

---

I just installed `Visual Studio Code` to try it out, but I ran into a problem almost immediately when trying to install any extension (following [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/extension-gallery)).

After pressing `ctrl + p` or `F1` and then typing `Extension` and selecting `Install`, the program appears to search for a while. However, after a few seconds to a minute I see this error:

**Error** `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND marketplace.visualstudio.com marketplace.visualstudio.com:443`

[image]

And if I click out of the window before this message appears:

**Error** `socket hang up`

[image]

Has anyone else seen the same error and managed to overcome?

---

As mentioned in the comments, this seems to be discussed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/69). However, I can't apply any of the suggested fixes:

- Changing `.host` to `.hostname` in the file `src/vs/workbench/node/proxy.ts` : I can't find this file on my system.
- Changing the same (`.host` to `.hostname`) in the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\electron-main\sharedProcessMain.js` : I can't find the folder `electron-main` or the file `sharedProcessMain.js` on my machine.
- Changing `SSLStrict` to `true`

Comment: I suffered this error and solved it configuring a proxy. Have you tried this? Take a look here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/69

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/69 have you seen this?

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I checked that site but I still have no idea what to do as the fixes that they suggest don't seem to apply to me - unless I am being an idiot and just can't find the files

Comment: @acostela @misha130 I was able to update `http.proxy` and `http.proxyStrictSSL` but still seeing the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to install some extensions after my network admin disabled SSL Inspection on my machine.

This is not ideal as I wouldn't want this turned off for everything.

After re-enabling inspection, I set my `User Settings` to

`"http.proxyStrictSSL": true`

**I am still unable to download packages, but this does appear to be the problem.**

Comment: I changed this setting to false and it now allows me to download and install extensions.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

change DNSs to **(8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4)**

Comment: where and how to add this

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure if you have installed any extensions before (by typing @installed in the extensions panel) if haven't installed anything yet try deleting all the files this location  C:\Users\SYS_NAME.vscode\extensions. Restart the vscode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `http.proxySupport` so your WSL instance can talk over proxy

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Find: `Preferences: Open Settings JSON` and add the following line to your settings:

```
"http.proxySupport": "on"
```

you may also need to change your DNS in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

and change the nameserver to:

```
nameserver: 8.8.8.8
```

Et Voila!

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove defaultproxy from devenv.exe.config to get rid of forbidden 403 error.

Deleting this section from devenv.exe.config sorted my issue.

```
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress=xxxxx/>
    </defaultProxy>
```

*C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.xxxxx \devenv.exe.config*

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the message that 'error while installing extension..' in Visual Studio Code.
I solved it by following these steps

1- Go to Environment Variables > System Variables
2- Click on Path
3- Click on New
4- Paste the location of the Visual Studio Code
(For me it is C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code)
5- Click OK

Hope, it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I once had this experience. Uninstall and reinstalling/updating Vs code simply fixed the error.
https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Answer (score 0):

If you have not set any proxy Or might have issue with credentials

```
// file : settings.json
{
// comment below line or change according to your credentials 
// "http.proxy": "http://username:password@hostname:port/",
"http.proxyAuthorization": null,
// make it false
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
 }
```